# Simplifying expressions with Abs

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, assumptions

I have a long expression which seems really complicated due to some `Abs[]` terms that should be simplified. However, even with the right assumptions, the expression is not simplified.

For example

```
Assuming[-1 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= π/4 && L ∈ Integers && 1 - (-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] >= 0, Abs[1 - (-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b]] == 1 - (-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] // FullSimplify]
```

should return `True`, but instead it returns `(-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] <= 1`. 
On the contrary

```
Assuming[-1 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= π/4 && L ∈ Integers && 1 - E^(I π L) Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] >= 0, Abs[1 - E^(I π L) Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b]] == 1 - E^(I π L) Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] // FullSimplify]
```

returns `True`.

Why is that?

Note that the trick to replace `(-1)^L` with `E^(I π L)` do not always works, as in the case of

```
Assuming[-1 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= π/4 && 0 <= Q <= 1 && L ∈ Integers && 1 - E^(I π L) Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] >= 0 && 1 - 2 Q + E^(I π L) Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] > 0, Sqrt[Abs[(1 - E^(I π L)  Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b])/(1 - 2 Q + E^(I π L)  Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b])]] == Sqrt[(1 - E^(I π L)  Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b])/(1 - 2 Q + E^(I π L) Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b])] // FullSimplify]
```

Comment: All three return `True` in Version 9.0.1.0 (Windows 8 x64).

Comment: I am using version 10.0 (Windows 7 Home Premium x64)... are you aware of any differences or issues?

Comment: Nicola, [search this site for Version 10](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Version+10) returns quite a few differences/issues:) See also: [Version 10 Simplify](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Version+10+Simplify), [Version 10 Abs](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Version+10+Abs) and [Version 10 FullSimplify](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Version+10+FullSimplify)

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if someone else with Version 10 has my same results

Comment: I can confirm Nicola's results (`(-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] <= 1`,`True`,etc.) and I am on Mathematica 10.0.2 running on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: I obtain the following results on with Mathematica 9.0.1.0 and 10.0.2.0, both run under Windows 8.1 (64 bit): First expression same as Nicola and @Wizard; True for second; complicated expression for third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems like a bug, a rather silly one on the surface.  Consider the returned value in the OP's first bit of code.  When it is simplified using the equivalent assumption as coded by the OP, it does not return `True`.  A simple transformation of the inequality gets us to the result.

```
Simplify[(-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] <= 1, 
  1 - (-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] >= 0]
Simplify[(-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] <= 1, 
  1 - (-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] >= 0 /. lhs_ >= rhs_ :> -lhs <= -rhs // Simplify]
(*
  (-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] <= 1
  True
*)
```

If we do the same in the OP's code, we get the desired result.  It is hard to guess the scope of this restriction.  Apparently there is no normal form for an inequality.

```
Assuming[-1 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= π/4 && L ∈ Integers &&
     1 - (-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] >= 0 /. lhs_ >= rhs_ :> -lhs <= -rhs // Simplify, 
 Abs[1 - (-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b]] == 1 - (-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] // Simplify]
(*
  True
*)
```

It seems particularly odd, because I suspect that the inequality that the OP's code produces is transformed from the assumptions.  For instance, compare

```
Assuming[1 - (-1)^L x >= 0 && L ∈ Integers, 
  Simplify[Abs[1 - (-1)^L x] == 1 - (-1)^L x]]
Assuming[L ∈ Integers, 
  Simplify[Abs[1 - (-1)^L x] == 1 - (-1)^L x]]
(*
  (-1)^L x <= 1
  (-1)^L x + Abs[1 + (-1)^(1 + L) x] == 1
*)
```

It is also connected to the factor `(-1)^L`:

```
Assuming[1 - x >= 0, Simplify[Abs[1 - x] == 1 - x]]
(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following does not answer the Question, but may shed some light on it.

For convenience, name the two equations `eq1` and `eq2`, respectively.

```
eq1 = Abs[1 - (-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b]] == 1 - (-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b];
eq2 = Abs[1 - E^(I π L) Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b]] == 1 - E^(I π L) Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b];
```

The essence of the matter appears to be whether `FullSimplify` can recognize that the argument of `Abs` is non-negative, in which case it strips off the `Abs`, and recognizes the expression to be `True`.  Consider first the effect of making the first three assumptions listed in the Question

```
FullSimplify[{eq1[[1]], eq1[[2]], eq1}, -1 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= π/4 && L ∈ Integers]
FullSimplify[{eq2[[1]], eq2[[2]], eq2}, -1 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= π/4 && L ∈ Integers]
```

Both give the same result,

```
(* {Abs[-1 + (-1)^L*Sqrt[1 - a^2]*Cos[2*b]], 1 + (-1)^(1 + L)*Sqrt[1 - a^2]*
      Cos[2*b], (-1)^L*Sqrt[1 - a^2]*Cos[2*b] <= 1} *)
```

Even with enough information to  do so, `FullSimplify` is unable to determine that the argument of `Abs` is non-negative, as can be seen in the first entry.  Yet, `FullSimplify` of `eq1` (or `eq2`) itself returns, in effect, `1 - (-1)^L*Sqrt[1 - a^2]*Cos[2*b] >= 0`.  It is as though Mathematica, being unable to simplify the equation, returns the (correct) answer to another question but does not use that answer to simplify `Abs`.

Consider instead the effect of making only the last assumption listed in the Question

```
FullSimplify[{eq1[[1]], eq1[[2]], eq1}, 1 - (-1)^L Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] >= 0]
```

gives the same answer, even when told explicitly that the argument of `Abs` is non-negative.  On the other hand,

```
FullSimplify[{eq2[[1]], eq2[[2]], eq2}, 1 - E^(I π L) Sqrt[1 - a^2] Cos[2 b] >= 0]
```

returns

```
(* {1 - Sqrt[1 - a^2]*E^(I*L*Pi)*Cos[2*b], 1 - Sqrt[1 - a^2]*E^(I*L*Pi)*Cos[2*b], True} *)
```

In this case, Mathematica uses the assumption to eliminate `Abs`, and the equation reduces to `True`.